# Is there a way to embed Markdown in RST?

Tags: markdown, restructuredtext

I find that ReStructuredText (RST) is a better format for writing documentation than Markdown due to its flexibility and that it supports the notion of comments. However, Markdown is faster for simpler tasks, and is generally more supported in other clients.

This means I can't copy/paste messages I write in slack / google chat into an RST document because they use markdown syntax for code and not RST.

It would be nice if there was a way for me to specify a Markdown section in my RST document, so I can just prefix the section. Based on a quick google I'm thinking this is not possible, but I'm also not seeing the question posed directly.  So, I'm asking it now.

Is there anyway to write Markdown inside of an RST document?

Answer (score 1):

If you use MyST with Sphinx, then mixing reStructuredText and Markdown is flexible,

https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sphinx/use.html#include-markdown-files-into-an-rst-file

Answer (score 0):

How about conversion?  If your editor lets you run filters on regions you could cut and paste then convert with [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/).

In vim something like:

`:'<,'>!pandoc -fmarkdown -trst`